# Nested Impala query to find occurrences of an event twice

Tags: sql, impala

I have a table which contains employee name, employee ID and timestamp of times logged.

| employee id | employee name | event_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Harry | 2021-11-18T20:03:25Z |
| 1 | Harry | 2021-11-19T20:03:25Z |
| 1 | Harry | 2021-11-20T20:03:25Z |
| 2 | Charlie | 2021-11-18T20:03:25Z |

I need to find out compliance percentage. Basically the percentage of days logged in out of the difference between max day and min day . This can be done through the following in Impala

```
SELECT employee_id,employee_name
(count(distinct(cast(event_time as timestamp))))/(datediff(cast(max(event_time) as TIMESTAMP),cast(min(event_time) as timestamp))) * 100.0 as compliance_percentage
FROM employee
group by employee_id,employee_name;
```

Now if the event_time is to be considered compliant only if it occurs twice i.e if a person logs two times and only two times how can we write a query in Impala so that we get the required result?

For example if Harry has logged for exactly 2 times on 8 different days  between 1st Feb 2021 and 1st Feb 2022 this would be the expected result(cp would be (8/365 * 100)

| employee_id | employee_name | cp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Harry | 2.19 |

Comment: I think it would make sense to show how your _expected result_ should look like with the given sample data

Comment: @StefanWuebbe I have added the expected result. Thank you.